# Integrate terminal shell in monaco editor

Tags: terminal, editor, monaco-editor

I want to use Monaco editor along with the integrated terminal ( like xterm.js) in the editor.
Is there any way to do this in the Monaco codebase?
basically any shell terminal extension/plugin available for Monaco editor?

Comment: Did you find out the answer to this question?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short list of projects which are integrating a Monaco editor with a terminal:

1. [Eclipse Theia](https://theia-ide.org/) "An Open, Flexible and Extensible Cloud & Desktop IDE Platform"
2. [Visual Studio Code Server](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/vscode-server) "The VS Code Server is currently a private preview."
3. [daedalOS](https://github.com/DustinBrett/daedalOS) "Desktop environment in the browser"